# What Significant Google Products Are Open Source?

Tags: open-source

I know that Google does **some** open source but a lot of their assets are very closed source.  What are the main ones that are open source and those not?

- Android - fully open (I think)
- GMail - Closed
- Search - Obviously closed
- Chrome - Some open source bits (webkit)... but I'm not sure
- JavaScript compilers (that Steve Yegge is working with)
- Youtube - Closed
- Feedburner - Closed Blogger - Closed

I am struggling to come up with big pro-OSS products from Google.

Comment: Steve Yegge wasn't working on the compiler, he was just using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm a Google employee, and therefore obviously biased :)

Have a look at [this page](http://code.google.com/more/) for a fairly large list of our open source APIs and projects. (I'm particularly involved in [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) and the [C# port](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/).)

Other things to consider off the top of my head, some of which are no doubt on that list:

- [Google Java collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/)
- [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) (Google Web Toolkit)
- [Wave](http://wave.google.com) (in the future)

You might also consider [code.google.com](http://code.google.com) to be a "pro-OSS product" in its own right.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is entirely open-source, as [Chromium](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/).

Answer (score 1):

[Google CTemplate](http://code.google.com/p/google-ctemplate/), a templating library for C++.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/ ZXing multi-format 1D/2D barcode image processing library implemented in Java. Possibly it's not the main one and not the highest quality but I've found it useful and open-source as opposed to most other such libraries.

Answer (score 0):

[Jaiku](http://code.google.com/p/jaikuengine/), as of recenty.